# Ruby/Rails return hash element if hash value is a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

In my Rails 6 and Ruby 2.7 app I'm trying to return only these hash elements which hash value is a string. The catch is that this hash has other hashes in it (so it's hash of hashes). Like below:

```
hash = {
  language: 'EN',
  details: {
    resultRanges: {
      book: {
        title: 'Dunder Mifflin',
        available: true,
        rank: -1.0,
        label: 'gray',
      },
    },
  },
}
```

From that hash I should get something like:

```
{
  language: 'EN',
  details: {
    resultRanges: {
      book: {
        title: 'Dunder Mifflin',
        label: 'gray',
      },
    },
  },
}
```

I've no clue how to do it. If I use `hash.keys` I'll get `[:language, :details]` so I cannot use something like `hash.select { |k, v| v.is_a?(String) }` because it will give me only the first hash key - `{:language=>"EN"}`.

Comment: Can you clarify your question, please? In the title of your question, you ask for hash *keys* which are strings, and in the body of your question, you ask for hash *values* which are strings. Which of the two is it?

Comment: @JörgWMittag oh yeah, good catch! it's about the values like in attached example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need here is a recursion, i.e. a function, calling itself:

```rb
def filter_hash(hash)
  hash.each_with_object({}) do |(key, value), acc|
    acc[key] = value if value.is_a?(String)
    acc[key] = filter_hash(value) if value.is_a?(Hash)
  end
end
```

This function checks if the value of your hash is `String`, then it saves it, if it's a `Hash` it calls itself with that nested Hash

Comment: That's great! Just wondering, what should I do to replace filtered_hash structure from `{ language: 'EN', details: { resultRanges: { book: { title: 'Dunder Mifflin', label: 'gray' }}}}` to be like `{ language: 'EN', details_resultRanges_book_title: 'Dunder Mifflin', details_resultRanges_book_label: 'gray' }` ?

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23521624/999223) will do the trick

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for a recursive function.

```
def recursively_delete(hash)
  hash.each do |k, v|
    if v.is_a?(Hash)
      recursively_delete(v)
    elsif !v.is_a?(String)
      hash.delete(k)
    end
  end
end

recursively_delete(hash)
p hash

=> {:language=>"EN", :details=> {:resultRanges=>{:book=>{:title=>"Dunder Mifflin", :label=>"gray"}}}}
```